# emailing confirmation to user when they submit an html registration form

Tags: php

I am trying to email the data in an html when you click on the submit button, the html form uses the POST action. My php code is:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$to      = '$email';                       //email submitted in html form
$subject = 'Welcome ';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: myaddress@email.com' . "\r\n".
'Reply-To: From: myaddress@email.com' . "\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if(!$result) {   
    echo "Error";   
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
?>
```

I get a success message but no email comes through, any ideas would be highly appreciated. many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Also unclear why you'd need `$to` when `$email` already exists.

Comment: change `$to = '$email';`    to    `$to = $email; ` and try again.

Comment: ken you're a legend! many thanks